# On how many ways can the teacher assign his grades

Tags: combinatorics

The question goes by:

`A class of 40 students are getting the grades A,B,C,D and F. The teacher fails half of his class, that is, 20 of the students get grade F. On how many possible ways can the teacher assign grades to his class?`

My idea is that the order doesn't matter, so we have a *combinations with repetitions* problem, that is, we will be using the formula $$\binom{k + n-1}{k}$$ where $k$ is the combinations (amount of students to be distributed) and $n$ is the objects (grades to distribute the students over).

So first we have 20 students to give F, and since the order does *not* matter, we get $$\binom{20 + 1-1}{20} = 1.$$

and for the remaining 20 students, we get $$\binom{20 + 4-1}{20} = \binom{23}{20} = 1771$$

so the final answer would be $1\cdot 1771 = 1771$.

But I'm not sure if this is correct... Anyone who can confirm or explain how this problem should be solved?

Comment: You’ve figured out how many ways there are for just one particular choice of the twenty students who get Fs. Do you see how to modify your answer to include all the ways in which the Fs can be assigned?

Comment: But isn't the twenty first students just FF....FF, 20 times (which can only be done in one way, since order doesn't matter)? When you are saying it like that, my guess would be 40C20, but I can't see what's wrong with my reasoning...

Comment: You seem very insistent that order doesn't matter, but I think it should... I'd care about the difference between "I get an A, and the person sitting next to me gets an F" and "I get an F, and the person sitting next to me gets an A"!

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes you are correct, I find it hard to distinguish between different types of combinatoric problems. When I read "On how many possible ways can the teacher assign grades to his class?" I think about it as the gradings AAB, ABA and BAA (as a short example) are all the same... Perhaps that's what confuses me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you choose which 20 students will be given an F. This is combinations without repetitions, because the same student can't be given an F twice, and order does not matter. So, there are $\binom{40}{20}$ ways to assign half of the class a grade of F.
Then, for each of the 20 remaining students, you assign them an A, B, C or D. There are 4 different choices for each student. This is permutation with repetition (as multiple students can have the same grade) and where order matters. So, there are $4^{20}$ ways to grade the rest of the class.
The total answer should be $\binom{40}{20}\times 4^{20}$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I can perhaps agree with the first 20 students. But doesn't "On how many possible ways can the teacher assign grades to his class?" mean that (as a short example) the gradings AB and BA are the same? 4^20 seem to differ AB and BA from each other...

Comment: I would assume AB (Maria gets an A and Jayla gets a B) is different from BA (Maria gets a B and Jayla gets an A). The students in the class are distinguishable.

Comment: @SteveKass I read it more as (20 F's, 20 A's) is one way, (20 F's, 19 A's, 1 B) is another way. But I suppose I misunderstood the question. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @aaa it does seem like a bit of an ambiguous question. If this is for an assignment or something, I'd definitely explain your interpretation of the problem just to be safe.